# Ocelot not finding reroutes files

Tags: docker, microservices, ocelot

I am trying to build my own micro services architecture and am stuck at the API.Gateway part.
I am trying to make **Ocelot V14** find all configuration **ocelot.json or configuration.json** files inside the **.sln** file.

[image: Solution File Set up]

In the **Program.cs** file I am trying to merge configuration files with the following code from this link https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#react-to-configuration-changes

```
builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton(builder))
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
             {
                 config
                     .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                     .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                     .AddOcelot(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment)
                     .AddEnvironmentVariables();
             })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

When I run this the application creates the following **ocelot.json** file inside my **OcelotApiGw Project**

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
  ]
}
```

The problem is that it is empty and the reroutes do not work. When I paste the desired reroutes into this **ocelot.json** file the reroutes work, that is not the desired functionality I want.

What I want is to merge the configuration file automatically from different **.json** files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**How eShopOnContainers implements it this way with Ocelot V12**

```
        IWebHostBuilder builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton(builder))
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ic => ic.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine("configuration", "configuration.json")))
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

In case you need more code, file structures or anything else just comment and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for? This is the way Ocelot merges multiple routing files together

https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#merging-configuration-files

We don't use this but this is how we have our startup defined:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddJsonFile(this.env.IsDevelopment() ? "ocelot.json" : "ocelot.octopus.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

So we have our standard appSettings plus the Ocelot one we use that Octopus will transform various variables we want when our Ocelot instance is deployed out into our test/production envs (or just our test/local one).

This seems to be the bit that defines what to do for multiple files:

> In this scenario Ocelot will look for any files that match the pattern
>   (?i)ocelot.([a-zA-Z0-9]*).json and then merge these together. If you
>   want to set the GlobalConfiguration property you must have a file
>   called ocelot.global.json.

Not sure if you need to explicitly define each file (unless they can be defined via a variable like {env.EnvironmentName}) but that should be easy enough to test.

Sorry if I have got the wrong end of the stick but hope this helps.